# Initial Ideal have linear resolution

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

The ideal $J$ is generated by the set $B$ of all binomials and
$B$ forms a Grobner basis for $J$ with respect to the lexicographic order. Let $in(J)$ denote the initial ideal of $J$.

For non-negative
integers $i, j$, let $\beta_{i,j}(I)$ denote the $(i,j)$-th graded Betti
number of $I$.
A homogeneous ideal $I$ of degree $d$ admits a linear resolution if $\beta_{i,i+j}(I)=0$ for all $j\neq d$.

> If $(in(J))^s$ has linear resolution for all q, then $in(J^s)$ has linear resolution?